# The bubble chart d3 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a bubble chart for class, but somehow it doesn't work at all, I checked the code again and again, couldn't find what's wrong with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>bubble</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var diameter = 500, //max size of the bubbles
color = d3.scale.category20b(); //color category

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
.sort(null)
.size([diameter, diameter])
.padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter)
.attr("height", diameter)
.attr("class", "bubble");

d3.csv("fruit.csv", function(error, data){

//convert numerical values from strings to numbers
data = data.map(function(d){ d.value = +d["Amount"]; return d; });

//bubbles needs very specific format, convert data to this.
var nodes = bubble.nodes({children:data}).filter(function(d) { return     !d.children; });

//setup the chart
var bubbles = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .selectAll(".bubble")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter();

//create the bubbles
bubbles.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); });

//format the text for each bubble
bubbles.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d){ return d["Fruit"]; })
    .style({
        "fill":"white", 
        "font-family":"Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, san-serif",
        "font-size": "12px"
    });
})
</script>
</html>
```

And this is the data file I'm using, the file name is fruit.csv. I did check everything line by line, couldn't find anything wrong

```
Fruit,Amount
Apple,32
Orange,89
Banana,15
```

Comment: You have a problem somewhere else, because the code and the CSV are OK. Are you using a server? Is the CSV in the same folder? What error do you get in the console, if any?

Comment: No, I don't use a server, and the CSV file is in the same folder, I will take a screenshot of console error though

Comment: yeah, you'll want to run it in a server, otherwise there's a chrome-setting you may need to use to allow the loading of files locally. have you tried running it in firefox?

Comment: I mean How to run in a server, sorry, guys, I'm not Computer Science major, I'm arts major.....

Comment: Just google *"how to run a local web server"*, there are several options. On Windows I use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)